# struts2 jquery plugin wraps html to returned id

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2

I am using struts2-jquery plugin in my project. I am trying to submit a form using `<sj:submit>` tag like this:

```
<sj:submit id="caseSubmit"
           targets="result"
           formIds="mainForm"
           onCompleteTopics="caseSubmitted"
           button="true"/>
```

The struts.xml mapping for this action is as follows:

```
  <action name="submitAddCase" class="com.xxx.action.AddCaseAction">
    <result type="json">
           <param name="root">caseId</param>
    </result>
  </action>
```

The onComPleteTopics code

```
$.subscribe('caseSubmitted', function(event,data) {
    var indexPre = event.originalEvent.request.responseText.indexOf("<pre>")+5;
    var indexPreEnd = event.originalEvent.request.responseText.indexOf("</pre>");
    var id = event.originalEvent.request.responseText.substring(indexPre,indexPreEnd);
    $("#case_id").val(id);
});
```

What I want is to use the `caseId` returned to load some other stuff on the same page. But,
`event.originalEvent.request.responseText` returns `caseId` wrapped in pre tag like this

```
<pre>154000</pre>
```

This is how it is returned in firefox. In chrome it is returned in another form. How can I get th caseId's original value without wrapped html.
Right now I am using javascript's substring method to get the value it is not working in chrome because of a different returned format

Comment: Strange... I can't replicate this/don't have this problem in Firefox.  What is #case_id element? What does caseId look like in your Java class?

Comment: caseId is an Integer variable, a primary key for Case entity.After submitting the case I am returning this id of newly created case into #case_id element so that it can be used later to show other info about the case.

Comment: What comes back should be a JSON string which you can parse with `obj = JSON.parse(event.originalEvent.request.responseText);` to get the elements but in your case, since it's just one integer it shouldn't be necessary to do this. Since you're getting some weird behaviors, you could try parsing the JSON returned first.  See if that gets rid of the `<pre>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#case_id").val(id);
```

with

```
$("#case_id").val($(id).html());
```

Comment: I was hoping that there will be a way to configure the plugin in such a way that it returns values without wrapping it. Tnx anyway. Also `id` doesnt represent any HTML element `caseId` does, so how can i use `$(id).html()`?

Comment: You can use any arbitrary html fragment as a selector.  Try $('<pre>154000</pre>').html(); in your console and you'll see that it strips off the pre tags.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that. Tnx. It seems a workable solution, I was thinking of adding browser detection code, but this is a better idea. Now I am starting to dislike this plugin. It doesnt let me create dynamic jquery datepickers.